# Many to Many relationship in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have what seems to be a simple question about EF 1.0 and have been looking all over the web for a simple answer, but have had no luck so far:

We're about to build a small application with SQL Server as the backend and have been considering using EF 1.0. Our company, like many large corporations, does not move quickly in adopting new platforms, which means .NET 4.0 won't be installed on machines for quite a while, so EF 4.0 is not a possibility.

Here's the question (based on an extremely simple example):

Three tables in a many to many relationship:

Order: OrderID (PK), Customer, OrderDate

OrderDetails: OrderDetailID (PK), OrderID (FK), ProductID (FK), Quantity, BackOrdered

Product: ProductID (PK), ProductName, Category

What we what to create is an Order instance that has the Order information and a list of the OrderDetails *including the **ProductName***

The SQL for this is trivial, so I won't bore you with that. And getting the Order and the list of OrderDetails is easy in EF 1.0, too. But when you get the list ProductID will identify the Product, and we need ProductName.

We've looked at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/associations-with-payloads-closing-the-loop). Is this the only way to accomplish what we need? Seems like a great deal of work...

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to insert an Order, with a list of its OrderDetails, each one of those having a Product. I assume the OrderDetails are new as well, thus needing insertion too, but what about the product, is it an existing product ?

Comment: Hm, I can't figure if you're trying to insert a new entity into the datastore, or to select an existing one with nav properties filled in.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in the question. It was the select I was looking for, and I think it's been answered. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extrapolating from your description, and if a select is what you're looking for, something along those lines could work :

```
var query = from o in context.Order
                             .Include("OrderDetails")
                             .Include("OrderDetails.Product")
            select o;
```

you can then access the information through navigation properties, such as:

```
// using first here just for exemple purpose.
Order o = query.First();
var details = o.OrderDetails;
var aProductName = o.OrderDetails.First().ProductName;
```